# AWS ECS trouble - Running shell script to boot program

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, docker, elixir, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run a Docker image on amazon ECS. I am using a command that starts a shell script to boot up the program:
`CMD ["sh","-c", "app/bin/app start; bash"]`
in order to start it because for some reason when I run the app (elixir/phoenix app) in the background it was crashing immediately but if I run it in the foreground it is fine. If I run it this way locally, everything works fine but when I try to run it in my cluster, it shuts down. Please help!!

Comment: In your terminal window in your development environment, if you run `app start`, do you get a shell prompt back immediately, or does the server run until you stop it with control-C?

Comment: Typically, `start` is used to start something in the background. Does the script provide a different subcommand, such as `run`, to keep the process in the foreground?

Comment: When I would run the app release in my terminal using start using “docker run -d app” , it would crash immediately leaving me with no recoverable logs or any running container. If I run the same command above with the CMD in the Dockerfile being “sh”,”-c”,”app/bin/app start; bash” it works but not if the CMD in the Dockerfile is simply app/bin/app start

Comment: So sh -c approach works locally but crashes when I try to run it in ECS

Answer (score 1):

Docker was supposed to keep track of your running foreground process, if the process stop, the container stop. The reason your container work when you use command with "bash" because bash wasn't stop.

I guess you use she'll script to start an application that serve in background like nginx or a daemon. So try to find an option that make the app running foreground will keep your container alive. I.e nginx has an option while starting "daemon off"

Answer (score 1):

> for some reason when I run the app (elixir/phoenix app) in the background it was crashing immediately

So you have a corrupted application and you are looking for a kludge to make it looking like it somewhat works. This is not a reliable approach at all.

Instead you should:

- make it working in background
- use `systemctl` or `upstart` to manage restarts of Erlang VM on crashes

Please note that it matters where you have your application compiled. It must be the exactly same architecture/container as the production one, with same Erlang, Elixir, OS versions, otherwise nobody guarantees it will be robust or even working.

Comment: The interesting thing is that when I run the production app locally in the background outside of the container, it worked fine. It was only when I tried to run the background process in the docket container that I encountered the problem and resorted to the shell script.

Comment: To run it in the docker you have to have it compiled in the very same docker.